# how To sort char name in a struct using C Language

Tags: c, sorting

how can you sort char firstName in a function and the names are read in from a text file already and external libraries can be used as well
All students names are provided in a text file, which is read into an array of student records

```
struct student{
   char*lastName; /*name of the student*/
   char*firstName;
   int age;       /*age of the student*/
   float grade[3];
}
```

Comment: You can format code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K. Use the preview.

Comment: Also, your question doesn't provide nearly enough information. What kind of array/collection do you have? This struct doesn't tell us anything.

Answer (score 4):

The `qsort` function is typically used in C to sort an array. One of the parameters is a pointer to a comparison function. Write the function so that it compares the two pointers in any fashion you want. You can even have different comparison functions so that you have the choice at run-time which will be applied.

```
int StudentCompare(const void * elem1, const void * elem2)
{
    const struct student * left = (const struct student *) elem1;
    const struct student * right = (const struct student *) elem2;
    int result;
    result = strcmp(left.firstName, right.firstName);
    if (result == 0)
        result = strcmp(left.lastName, right.lastName);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: In reference to the qsort(3) man page, you'll see that StudentCompare() is the 'compar' argument.  If you have struct student students[100];, then you would call qsort(students, 100, sizeof(struct student), StudentCompare);

Comment: Also, I think it should be 'struct student' instead of just 'student' in the StudentCompare() implementation.

Comment: @Wade, thanks for that. I've been spoiled by C++ for far too long. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way, assuming you're not allowed to use external libraries, is with bubblesort. Write a function that determines if an array of `struct student`s is already sorted. Then write a function that walk through such an array, comparing adjacent pairs of students. If they're out of order, swap them. Use the first function's result as the conditional clause of a while loop and the second function as the body.

If you are allowed to use it, then `qsort()` from `stdlib.h` is by far the best approach.

Comment: Insertion sort is typically a touch simpler and a touch faster.  Also, `qsort()` is not an external library, but is included in the C standard library.